# Pass object as parameter in GET request using Google Http Client

Tags: json, http, httpclient, jackson

I'm using Google Http Client and Jackson to query data to backend (JSON API).

I need to pass parameters (one Java bean object). The object might have few or lot of field. Initially I attempt to pass it as content as follow:

`HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(getUrl(api)).setContent(new JsonCContent(jsonFactory, params));`

However, I'm not allowed to set the HTTP content in GET operation.

Any suggestion how can I pass these parameters?

Under one condition: 
I don't want to write a util method to convert this object into string of URL parameters. But if there's already reusable API to do it, that would be fine.

I need generic solution if possible. Because I'm going to apply this to 600 JSON API calls.

My last alternative would be to change backend to expect POST request instead of GET, then I perform POST operation on the client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Instead of extends GenericUrl, you can use GenericUrl.put (inherit from GenericData) to set query parameters. For example:

```
GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl("http://yourapi.com/request");
genericUrl.put("user", "user name");
genericUrl.put("token", "token value");
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the expected usage is to extend the URL class you are using for your `buildGetRequest()` call. For instance, let's say you wanted to provide two extra query parameters called "user" and "token". You could do this with the following:

```
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(
    new CustomUrl("http://www.yourserver.com").setUser(userId).setToken(token));
```

where the `CustomUrl` class is defined as:

```
public class CustomUrl extends GenericUrl {
    public CustomUrl(String encodedUrl) {
        super(encodedUrl);
    }

    @Key("user")
    private String mUserId;

    @Key("token")
    private String mToken;

    public CustomUrl setUser(String userId) {
        mUserId = userId;
        return this;
    }

    public CustomUrl setToken(String token) {
        mToken = token;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The values are not necessary for the `@Key` annotations, but will be used as the name of the respective query parameters if provided. If omitted, the name of the variable will be used instead ([see example](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/dailymotion-simple-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/dailymotion/cmdline/simple/DailyMotionSample.java?repo=samples#85))

Check [google-http-client's javadoc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/GenericUrl.html) for more info.

Comment: with your suggested solution, for each java beans I need to send as parameter, I have to create one custom URL object for that. Well, that's not what I want. thanks anyway